# HTML tags are removed from tags' excerpts

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, markdown-rendering

Have a look at [textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textarea) tag page. There was an excerpt, that had the following contents:

```
A <textarea> is an HTML element (tag) used to create a multi-line plain-text editing field.
```

But the `<textarea>` text was not visible in the browser:
[image]

I thought that wrapping it with `` ` `` would solve the problem so I edited the excerpt. But it did not - now the text *A `` is an HTML...* is being displayed.

Comment: Looks like that is by design: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts

Comment: @rene, I understand why markdown is not allowed in excerpts. But escaping HTML tags instead of removing them would be a better idea.

Comment: Not even HTML entities work. I agree that this is a bug; if no formatting is allowed then angle brackets should just be escaped.

Comment: They must have changed something in how that gets rendered. Pretty sure you used to be able to simply type out <textarea> and the system would escape them for you and display the text (which is what happens if you click the "show excerpt" button on the tag wiki page, but not in the excerpt on the questions list page).

Comment: The same bug reported on [meta.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232023/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me too.

In excerpts, [no formatting is allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts). Unfortunately, it looks like text in angle brackets is simply removed altogether, and using `&lt;textarea&gt;` just produces the literal text.

With the field being treated as plain text, angle brackets should be escaped using `&lt;` and `&gt;` on display, not stripped.

Comment: I am curious if \<textarea\> would work; It does work wonders when trying to write something that looks like formatting.

Comment: @Sumurai8: but *all formatting is ignored*. Unfortunately, HTML tags are removed *as well*. So `\<textarea\>` just results in the literal text being shown, backslashes and all.